# Select Duplicate column having multiple non distinct parent

Tags: sql-server

[Below is my table structure displayed in Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dhglh.png)

[I am creating a query which will give me a result like Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbEam.png)

I have created the below query but it is not giving me the expected result

```
select v.attributeCd , v.parentObject_id  
from Mapping v where v.parentObject_id in ( 
    select distinct(v1.parentObject_id) 
    from Mapping v1)   
group by v.attributeCd , v.parentObject_id 
having count(v.attributeCd) > 2 order by attributeCd
```

Comment: Please present tables as text, or better yet `CREATE TABLE` / `INSERT` statements, so we can actually reproduce queries and results (using a site like [this](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/), for example). Producing text is much less work for you than typing out images is for us.

Comment: Current Table Values as below

+-----------------+-----------------+
|   attributeCd   | parentObject_id |
+-----------------+-----------------+
| AccountNumber   |             218 |
| AdditionalWeeks |              46 |
| AdminCharges    |              29 |
| AdminCharges    |             230 |
| AgeCategoryCd   |              56 |
| AgeCategoryCd   |             155 |
| AgentDivisionCd |             118 |
| AgentNum        |             275 |
| AgentNum        |             445 |
| EntryAge        |               4 |
+-----------------+-----------------+

Comment: Expected output is

+---------------+-----------------+
|  attributeCd  | parentObject_id |
+---------------+-----------------+
| AdminCharges  |              29 |
| AdminCharges  |             230 |
| AgeCategoryCd |              56 |
| AgeCategoryCd |             155 |
| AgentNum      |             275 |
| AgentNum      |             445 |
+---------------+-----------------+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GMB Mentioned you could do a window count.

```
DECLARE @Mapping AS TABLE
(
    attributeCd         VARCHAR(20)
    ,parentObject_id    INT
)

INSERT INTO @Mapping 
(
    attributeCd 
    ,parentObject_id
)
VALUES
 ('AccountNumber',218)
,('AdditionalWeeks',46)
,('AdminCharges',29)
,('AdminCharges',230)
,('AgeCategoryCd',56)
,('AgeCategoryCd',155)
,('AgentDivisionCd',118)
,('AgentNum',275)
,('AgentNum',445)
,('EntryAge',4)
,('ExpiryDt',181)
,('ExpiryDt',184)
,('ExpiryDt',186)

select  attributeCd ,parentObject_id
FROM
    (select 
        attributeCd
        ,parentObject_id
        ,CNT                = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY attributeCd)
    from 
        @Mapping) AS V
WHERE
    V.CNT > 1
ORDER BY 
    attributeCd
```

understand the result of sub query first to get the full picture of query.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a window count and filter by that:

```
select attributeCd, parentObject_id
from (select t.*, count(*) over(partition by attributeCd) cnt from mytable)
where cnt > 1
```

This will give you records for which there are at least another record with the same `attributeCd`.

Comment: Above answered query is not clear to me can you please share the complete query

Comment: @nikhil: this is the complete query... Also I am quite suprised that you eventually accepted an answer that was posted after mine and whose code at is just (explictly) identical to mine.